# How to format a sting from another cell in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I must import values from two different cells into on, the first park shall be formatted as bold.

It should be pretty easy to do:

```
=TEXT(Datasheet!W3; "Bold") & " " & Datasheet!X3
```

But the it isn't formatting the first section :-|

Then I discovered that it might be a language issue, and I tried writing the format code in Danish

```
=TEXT(Datasheet!W3; "Fed") & " " & Datasheet!X3
```

It is still not working
The I tried including a strict formatting on behalf of a language:

```
=TEXT(Datasheet!W3; "[$-en-US]Bold") & " " & Datasheet!X3
```

Not working either, I also tried:

```
=TEXT(Datasheet!W3; [$-en-US]"Bold") & " " & Datasheet!X3
```

Still no luck :-|

Anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Comment: You can't apply that syntax within the `TEXT()` function.

Comment: What can I do then to archive either keeping the formatting from the original cell og format the first included cell?

Comment: You will need to use VBA and write a text string to the cell in order to differentially format the font characteristics of a portion of the string. You cannot do this when the text is a result of a formula in the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text function does not provide that kind of formatting. You'll either need to do it manually or create a VBA macro. There may also be solutions with Office Scripts in Excel.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel

The TEXT function lets you change the way a number appears by applying formatting to it with format codes. It's useful in situations where you want to display numbers in a more readable format, or you want to combine numbers with text or symbols.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/text-function-20d5ac4d-7b94-49fd-bb38-93d29371225c

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply !!

I just found a guide that is referring to the way I am doing it, but I assume that guide isn't valid?
https://www.causal.app/excel/how-to-match-formatting-when-concatenating

Would it be possible somehow to keep the formatting from the included cells?

Comment: @PNR That guide seems wrong with regard to the `TEXT` function.  And also, AFAIK, `CONCATENEX` is a DAX function, not an Excel function. Maybe he has an as yet unreleased version of Excel?

Answer (score 0):

The Worksheetfunction.Text method is to display a value as text with the following parameters from Microsoft definition.

WorksheetFunction.Text Method

Converts a value to text in a specific number format.
Syntax

expression.Text(Arg1, Arg2)

**expression**   A variable that represents a WorksheetFunction object. In a worksheet cell replace it with **equal sign** `(=Text(....))`

**Parameters**

**Arg1** Required Variant A numeric value, a formula that evaluates to a numeric value, or a reference to a cell containing a numeric value.

**Arg2** Required String A number format in text form in the Category box on the
Number tab in the Format Cells dialog box. (Cell right-click **Format cells...**
)

**Return Value**
String

```
Since Excel applies cell formatting you can't format individual characters in a cell.
```